# How to extract data from form input data-bind generated in realtime

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, python-requests, http-headers, azure-active-directory

I am trying to automate a task of authentication via Azure ActiveDirectory. I was writing my script as per the browser requests. On seeing the request, I notice that browser is sending a parameter in url-encoded form.

The parameter is being sent as **i19**.

```
<input type=hidden name=i19 data-bind=\"value: timeOnPage\"/>'
```

On going through internal scripts of the page I find the above input type where **i19** is being assigned a value dynamically.

I need to generate this value to form a encoded string parameter to be sent to next location url for authentication.

It does not look like an EPOCH UNIX timestamp either.

For Eg: At roughly about 13:53:58 IST,  **i19: 55964**

Now I am unable to find what exactly is going in this i19.

I am attaching a response script [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GSum0RcpoxS7D6sO0uEBp_AFKZnUZ4072cLijw4Xc2k/edit?usp=sharing) for the script where this input is being generated.(It is a long file so attached separately). All I know that some value is being created dynamically and browser understands it but via python post request, javascript is disabled and the value is not being shown in response/headers/cookies.

I shall be really grateful for the same.

Comment: Note sure if this will help but this is [knockout.js](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) syntax. You can get the view model bound to the input by using `ko.dataFor( <element> )` You can get the element using `querySelector` or something similar

Comment: Hey, @adiga can you elaborate, on how to integrate the knockout syntax with python requests to read real-time generated value.

Comment: sorry, I don't know about python

Answer (score 0):

i faced a similar problem while trying to replicate the Microsoft login flow in JMeter, but it turns out that i19 does not require to be changed each time. I put a random number (6342) and it was working fine in my case.